# Indiscrete topological space is second countable.

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

Is uncountable indiscrete topological space (X, tau )is second countale ?
As far I know the only possible basis for the indiscrete topological space is X but since X is uncountable so its not second countable.
But the basis {X} has only one element that is X . Can we write set X in the basis as {X}. If we consider this then space is second countable.
Which perspective is correct ?

Comment: Never mind the indiscrete space, do you know **any** example of an uncountable topological space which is second countable? Do you believe that the real line (with the usual topology) is second countable? Because the elements of your countable base will be open sets, and every (nonempty) open subset of the line is uncountable!!!

Comment: Thanks I got it. So the basis of indiscrete topological  space is {X} , which is countable.

Answer (score 3):

Second countability requires a countable basis for the topology -- the countability or uncountability of the *space* is not part of the definition.  Further, it doesn't require that any particular basis be countable, only that somehow there *is* a countable basis.

In the indiscrete topology, $\tau = \{\varnothing, X\}$.  Note that $\tau$ is a (more than sufficient) basis for $\tau$ and $\tau$ is countable, so this topology is second countable.